# How to specify libraries only for Android platform build in .pro file?

Tags: android, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I'm trying to use QtCreator (2.7.2) + QT (5.1.0) to build an application that runs on both desktop (Linux) and mobile (Android) platforms.

To achieve this, I need to use different pre-built libraries depending on the target platform.
How do I specify this in the .pro file?

The wizard only offers linux/mac/windows as platform choice like

```
unix:!mac {
message("* Using settings for Unix/Linux.")
LIBS += -L/path/to/linux/libs
}
```

I've tried

```
android { 
message("* Using settings for Android.")
LIBS += -L/path/to/android/libs
}
```

But with both build targets only the `unix:!mac` gets executed/evaluated.

So my question is: How to detect the build target (called "Kits" now in QtCreator) in the .pro file and change library definitions accordingly?

I've so far only found out how to specify the platform (which seems to be the platform I'm building ON and not FOR) or the build variant RELEASE/DEBUG.
Other things I've found say I should prefix the `LIB+=` with the target platform like `win32:LIB+=`. But again, this won't work with `android`. Maybe I'm using a wrong syntax for the platform (android 4.2 on an arm-v7).

Comment: Hi, have you got boost successfully working with Qt on android? I got a problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433059/boost-filesystem-func-crashes-with-qt-for-android. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this works for me (Qt 5.3.2)

```
linux:!android {
    message("* Using settings for Unix/Linux.")
    LIBS += -L/path/to/linux/libs
}

android { 
    message("* Using settings for Android.")
    LIBS += -L/path/to/android/libs
}
```

Comment: Seems to be new in Qt 5.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this in a .pro file, maybe it helps:

```
unix:!macx:
{
    android:
    {
        INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/lib/boost/boost_1_47_0" \
                       inkscape
    }
    !android:
    {
        INCLUDEPATH += $$(BOOST_PATH) \
                    inkscape
    }
}
macx:
{
    INCLUDEPATH += "../../../../boost_1_54_0" \#$$(BOOST_PATH) \
                    inkscape
}
```