# How can we support android and iOS platform with using only one .pro file in Qt?

Tags: qt

Presently I have to make separate Qt projects for Android and iPhone as androidextras module has to be included in .pro file which causes error when building for iOS.

Can I include modules in .pro file conditionally according to target device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify libraries only for Android platform build in .pro file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104716/how-to-specify-libraries-only-for-android-platform-build-in-pro-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional branching in pro files.

```
android { 
    QT += androidextras
}
```

Have a look to this similar question: [How to specify libraries only for Android platform build in .pro file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104716/how-to-specify-libraries-only-for-android-platform-build-in-pro-file)